# Hash anchor tag causing errors in URL

Tags: coldfusion, railo, fusebox

On very rate occasions, my error log is showing the following error:
"You specified a Fuseaction of registrationaction#close which is not defined in Circuit public."

```
The full link is:"http://myUrl/index.cfm?do=public.registrationAction#close"
```

As you can see, the has merely points to an anchor (close) on the page. 
This code is working 99% of the time, but on the odd occasion, Coldfusion / Fusebox throws this error out.

Why is this happening?

Could it be related to the device accessing my page somehow? Like a cell phone or Apple product that for some reason does handle hashes the way I am expecting it to?

Could it be javascript / JQuery being disabled?

Any guidance would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: have u tried asking there? http://www.fusebox.org/forums/

Comment: Hi Henry. Thanks, but those forums are a ghost town! =)

Answer (score 1):

I used to see stuff like that. Older versions of Internet Explorer were not handling the hashtag properly when there were URL parameters. The best solution I could come up with was kludgey at best, but basically it forced the anchor tag to separate from the URL parameter.

```
http://myUrl/index.cfm?do=public.registrationAction&#close
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there is a simple answer to this. We get odd exceptions all the time on our site for all sorts of reasons. Sometimes it's people not using the site the way you expect and sometimes it stuff like you mention such as user-agent edge cases etc.

Basically you need to start to gather evidence and see what comes up that's unusual with these requests.

So to start: do you catch exceptions in you application? If so dumping all scopes (`CGI/CLIENT/FORM/URL/SESSION`) in an email along with the full exception and emailing them to a custom emails address (such as `errors@yourdomain.com`) will give you a reference you can square up to your error times and this might give you a hint as to the real issue.

Hope that helps some!

Comment: Hi Ciaran. What you suggested is exactly what I do. Unfortunately, those dumps don't help at all for this error. I managed to resolve 90% of errors by the info that's mailed to me, but in this case it's no help :(